# Send a list of objects as a navigation parameter

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have an app that lets people view information about specific films. In my MainPage (GenreListPage) I have a list that sorts every film in the database into a list of genres. The genre type and number of films of the same genre are displayed in a CollectionView ItemTemplate (GenreModel). When a user taps on a genre, they navigate to another page with another CollectionView (FilmListPage). this CollectionView is populated with an ItemTemplate containing the film title and rating (FilmModel).

Currently, when the user navigates to the FilmListPage the constructor calls a method that queries a database, retrieving all films with the specified genre chosen in the GenreListPage.

I want to change this so I have included a List of type FilmModel to my GenreModel. When I navigate to the FilmListPage, I want to pass the FilmModel list as a parameter and retrieve it in the FilmListPage. However from my understanding passing navigation parameters only means passing strings. Is this true?

Some code;

GenreModel.cs

```
public class GenreModel{

    public string GenreType {get; set;}

    public List<FilmModel> AssociatedFilms {get; set;}
}
```

FilmModel.cs

```
public class FilmModel {

    public string Title {get; set;}

    public double Rating {get; set;}
}
```

GenreListPageViewModel.cs

```
public class GenreListPageViewModel.cs  : ViewModelBase
{
    private GenreModel _selectedGenre;
    private List<GenreModel> _genres;

    public GenreModel SelectedGenre 
    {
        get => _selectedGenre;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedGenre, value);
    }

    public List<GenreModel> Genres
    {
        get => _genres;
        set => SetProperty(ref _genres, value);
    }

    public GenreListPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDatabaseService databaseService) : base (navigationService)
    {
        Genres = new ObservableCollection<GenreModel>(databaseService.GetFilms());
    }

    public async void ItemSelected()
    {
        var p = new NavigationParameters;
        p.Add("Films", SelectedGenre.AssociatedFilms);
        p.Add("Genre", SelectedGenre.GenreType);
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("FilmListPage", p);
    }
}
```

FilmListPageViewModel.cs

```
public class FilmListPageViewModel.cs : ViewModelBase, INavigationAware
{
    IDatabaseService _databaseService;

    private string _genre;
    private List<FilmModel> _films = new List<FilmModel>();

    public string Genre
    {
        get => _genre;
        set => SetProperty(ref _genre, value);
    }

    public List<FilmModel> Films
    {
        get => _films;
        set => SetProperty(ref _films, value);
    }

    public GenreListPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDatabaseService databaseService) : base (navigationService)
    {
        _databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        Genre = parameters.GetValue<string>("Genre")};

        //old code that used to get film by selected genre
        //Films = databaseService.GetFilmsByGenre(Genre);

        Films = new ObservableCollection<FilmModel>(parameters.GetValues<FilmModel>("Films"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Navigation and Dialog Parameters are actually `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. So what does this mean for you?

Well for starters it means that any given key may contain one to many actual values.

```cs
navigationParameters.Add("message", "Prism is great for Wpf apps");
navigationParameters.Add("message", "Prism is great for Xamarin.Forms apps");
navigationParameters.Add("message", "Prism is great for Uno and WinUI apps");
```

Second it means that's you can pass literally anything you want as a parameter.

```cs
var messages = new[] {
    "Prism is great for Wpf apps",
    "Prism is great for Xamarin.Forms apps",
    "Prism is great for Uno and WinUI apps"
};
navigationParameters.Add("message", messages);
```

As you're probably familiar you can pull parameters back out like:

```cs
var messages = navigationParameters.Get<IEnumerable<string>>("message");
```

If you were to use this method using the first way you added messages you would likely get an exception because it would hit the first value and see it's not the same type. If you added it the second way this would still work because you added an `IEnumerable<string>`.

There is however a second method that works great for what you're looking for and would work regardless of how your values got added.

```cs
var messages = navigationParameters.GetValues<string>("message");
```

The `GetValues` method returns an IEnumerable of the given generic type.

Comment: ohhh I see. so If I wanted to return my list, I would use the list object type in the <> tags? Like `navigationParameters.GetValues<FilmModel>("Films");` ?

Answer (score 0):

> However from my understanding passing navigation parameters only means passing strings. Is this true?

Luckily, no, the value associated with a key can be anything (have a look at [the code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Forms/Prism.Forms/Navigation/INavigationParameters.cs)):

```
public interface INavigationParameters : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
```